# Relation between MDPs and non-deterministic finite automatons

Tags: fl.formal-languages, computability, automata-theory, regular-language, grammars

I'm confused as to the relation (computability-wise) between markov decision processes and NFAs. Are finite state MDPs expressible as regular grammars?  If so, are markov decision processes thus solvable by nondeterministic finite automota?  Thank you, and my apologies in advance if this question is invalid/makes no sense.

Comment: How do you define the *language* accepted by an MDP?

Comment: You may want to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_automaton